# ||(Or) Logical Operator in Java vs .Net

Tags: c#, java, .net, logical-operators

I have been coding in Java(Mainly) and .Net for a while.

What I found is that the `||` logical operator in .Net is different in result to the `||` operator in Java.

Lets look at the following Java code:

```
Object obj = null;

if(obj == null || obj.toString().isEmpty()){
    System.out.println("Object is null");
}
```

The result of the code above will be:

**Object is null**

The reason for that is because `obj == null` is `true` and the second expression wasn't evaluated. If it was, I would have received a `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

And if I used the single or (`|`) I would also received a `NullPointerException` (Both are evaluated).

My question is the following:

***If the code was C#, I will always get a ObjectReferenceNotSet etc. exception because the obj value is null and the second expression is always evaluated (Regardless of the operator), meaning the result is different in C# than in Java.
If I would to change the C# code to work properly, I have to create two if statements.***

***Is there not an easier way to do this in C# to be similar to Java? (Keep it in one if with 2 expressions)***

Thank you.

Comment: i had to downvote you, sorry :( but your question is completely wrong and i can't understand why it's receiving multiple up votes!

Comment: I agree. I made a mistake on another location. I voted to close the question. As I am unable to delete it.

Comment: I confused myself with VB.Net. Received a NullReference and thought C# reacted in a similar fashion, problem was elsewhere.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `||` operator in C# is short-circuiting, just like in Java. As is `&&`. The `|` and `&` operators are *not* short-circuiting, just like in Java.

If your results are different, there is a bug in the code. Can you show us the offending C# please?

This works fine:

```
    object obj = null;

    if(obj == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.ToString())) {
        Console.WriteLine("Object is null");
    }
```

Comment: Would this also be the case for VB.Net when using Or?

Comment: @Koekiebox - no; in VB `OrElse` is short-circuiting; `Or` is **not** short-circuiting. Ditto `AndAlso` vs `And`

Answer (score 2):

The || operator has exactly the same meaning in Java and C#. It is called a **conditional logical OR**, or **"short-circuiting" logical OR** operator:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346%28VS.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour is a strict [java language feature](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.24):

> At run time, the left-hand operand
>   expression is evaluated first ;[...] if the resulting value is
>   true, the value of the conditional-or
>   expression is true and the right-hand
>   operand expression is not evaluated.
>   If the value of the left-hand operand
>   is false, then the right-hand
>   expression is evaluated; [...] the
>   resulting value becomes the value of
>   the conditional-or expression.
>
> Thus, || computes the same result as |
>   on boolean or Boolean operands. It
>   differs only in that the right-hand
>   operand expression is evaluated
>   conditionally rather than always

Similar rules are defined for the [java conditional-and operator](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.23).

Compare (identical) to C#:

> The `&&` and `||` operators are called
>   the conditional logical operators.
>   They are also called the
>   “short-circuiting” logical operators.
>
> *conditional-and-expression*:
>
> - *inclusive-or-expression*
> - *conditional-and-expression && inclusive-or-expression*
>
> *conditional-or-expression:*
>
> - *conditional-and-expression*
> - *conditional-or-expression || conditional-and-expression*
>
> The `&&` and `||` operators are conditional versions
>   of the `&` and `|` operators:
>
> - The operation `x && y` corresponds to the
>     operation `x & y`, except that `y` is
>     evaluated only if `x` is not `false`.
> - The operation `x || y` corresponds to
>     the operation `x | y`, except that `y` is
>     evaluated only if `x` is not true.

Comment: (added in the C# version as well, to show similarity)

Answer (score 0):

It's called "short circuit evaluation". There is no need to evaluate the next statement. This is a nice feature in Java.

Comment: But it's the same in C#.